# renaming the files using matlab

Tags: image, file, matlab, rename

I have some 100 .jpg files and I need to rename them like for example I have image98, image99, image100, image101 so on. I need to rename them as image098, image099, image100, image101. Can someone help me out with this?

```
dirData = dir('*.jpg');         
fileNames = {dirData.name};     
for iFile = 1:numel(fileNames)  
  newName = sprintf('image%04d.jpg',iFile);
  movefile(fileNames{iFile},newName);      
end
```

tried doing the above code but its not working properly.

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
dirData = dir('*.jpg');
fileNames = {dirData.name};
for iFile = 1:numel(fileNames)
  fileNum = str2num(regexprep(fileNames{iFile}, '[^0-9]', ''));
  movefile(fileNames{iFile}, sprintf('image%04d.jpg', fileNum));
end
```